# Regex with splitting a string with pipes

Tags: regex, ant

Can't figure this one out at all.

I have the following string `aaa||bbb||ccc`. I'd like to split by `||`.

I had a Regex that worked for `aaa||bbb` which was `(.*)\|\|(.*)` but that doesn't work for 3 values or more.

I need one to work for unlimited number of values.

Thanks

**EDIT**: Sorry forgot to mention. I'm using Ant with PropertyRegex task from Ant-Contrib library.

So basically just need the plain regex.

Comment: When it's always a sequence of two pipes, why not split by it using simple string operations (like string.Split in c#)? Even needs less computational work.

Comment: I'm confused: I don't think of `PropertyRegex` as "splitting" a string, since its result is always a *single* string, whereas "splitting" implies that the result is a collection of strings. Could you post the actual `<propertyregex .../>` tag you're using for your `aaa||bbb` case? That should help clarify what it is that you're doing . . .

Answer (score 3):

Instead of matching and using captured groups, you can split the string on `||` using the regex:

```
\|\|
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a variation of the following:

```
[^|]+(?:\|\|[^|]+)*
  1       2   1
```

Where `1` matches anything but a pipe and `2` matches your separator?

```
Matches-->aaa
Matches-->aaa||bbb
Matches-->aaa||bbb||ccc
Matches-->aaa||bbb||ccc||ddd
Does not match-->aaa||
Does not match-->aaa|bbb
Does not match-->aaa|bbb|ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a plain regex-match; rather, you need to use a "split" function of some stripe. This will depend on the language you're using. For example, in Java you could write:

```
final String[] fields = "aaa||bbb||ccc".split("[|][|]", -1);
```

or in Perl:

```
my @fields = split /\|\|/, 'aaa||bbb||ccc', -1;
```

If you update your question to indicate what language you're using, you'll get a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will resolve this

```
string x1 = "aaa||bbb||ccc";

string[] result = Regex.Split(x1, @"\|\|");
```

you can use this too

```
string[] parts = x1.Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use the split function from Ant Addon **[Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/)**, f.e. :

```
<project name="demo" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
 <property name="somestring" value="aaa||bbb||ccc"/>

 <fl:let>counter = 0</fl:let>
  <fl:for var="substring" in="split('${somestring}','\|\|')">
   <fl:let>counter = counter + 1</fl:let>
   <!-- simple echo -->
   <fl:echo>substring #{counter} => #{substring}</fl:echo>
   <!-- create properties for further processing -->
   <fl:let>substring#{counter} := '#{substring}'</fl:let>
  </fl:for>

  <echo>
   $${substring1} => ${substring1}
   $${substring2} => ${substring2}
   $${substring3} => ${substring3}
  </echo>
</project>
```

output :

```
Buildfile: /home/rosebud/AntTest/tryme.xml
  [fl:echo] substring 1 => aaa
  [fl:echo] substring 2 => bbb
  [fl:echo] substring 3 => ccc
     [echo]     ${substring1} => aaa
     [echo]     ${substring2} => bbb
     [echo]     ${substring3} => ccc
```